# Deleting Certain Items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a Minecraft realm, we made a base inside of an ocean monument but we keep having Guardians spawning. I have a command set up to kill them when they spawn, /kill @e[type=minecraft:guardian] , but I don't want the items that come with them dying cause that's just taking advantage of it. Is there a way where I can "kill" Prismarine Shards, Crystals, Raw Cod, and Raw Salmon right when they die and drop their items?

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 solutions for you. You can either burn them in lava or have them dropped for a long time and have them expire. Hope this helps!